# how to get selected value from list of radio buttons in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a list of radio buttons,value of those buttons came from ajax request inform of json data.i have binded it to list but i want to get selected value from the list,i tried as below with no luck.

**html**

```
   <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="area in AreaList">
      <label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item" >
          <input type="radio" ng-bind="area.name"  ng-model="selectedValue" name="area" value="area.code">
        <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark"></div>
        {{area.name}}
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
```

**js**

```
      //PARING FOR AREA
                if(data.Details[i] === "Area"){
                         for(var d=0;d<17;d++){

                             var area =data.Details[i+1][d]['varCityName'];
                             var code = data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode'];

                                 $scope.AreaList.push({name:area, code:code});

                                 area = '';
                                 code = '';

                                 $scope.selectedValue =  data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode'];

                    }

                    console.log("===========AREA obj===========",  $scope.AreaList);

       } 
.
.
.
.
 $scope.submitAnswer=function(list,rate,areaobj)
      {
       gList = list.name;

            alert("-----------my selected area is=========="+gArea);

     };
```

**area object printed in console.long**

```
[
    Object{
        name="Camana Bay",
        code="32"
    },
    Object{
        name="Breakers",
        code="1"
    },
    Object{
        name="Grand Cayman",
        code="2"
    },
    Object{
        name="Bodden Town",
        code="16"
    },
    Object{
        name="Cayman Brac",
        code="15"
    },
    Object{
        name="East End",
        code="20"
    },
    Object{
        name="George Town",
        code="21"
    },
    Object{
        name="George Town West",
        code="22"
    },
    Object{
        name="Little Cayman",
        code="23"
    }
   ]
```

Comment: have you tried removing the {{}} from value like so: value="area.code". Here are the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: @jax,no ,why? is it working..pls wait i am trying sir

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: Why are you setting selectedValue in every loop iteration?

Comment: @jax..ok pls wait..i never done,but i can try..

Comment: @mxa055 - so how will i get value of $selectedvalue sir?pls pls pls

Comment: I added a jsbin in my answer. Check it out.

Comment: @Jax-http://plnkr.co/edit/bnIDePckmmPBSkKFERWL?p=preview&utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation

Comment: [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/PQvQ2/1218/) a basic example of using ng-model for binding $scope.properties with checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="radio" ng-bind="area.name"  ng-model="selectedArea" name="area" ng-value="area.code">
```

**ng-model** takes the variable on which the selected value will be stored.

**ng-value** takes the value that will be stored in ng-model if the particular radio button will be selected

Check out [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yesoko/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: hi..please see my edit sir,is something missing?or looping error?as i am getting only the last value when i press button,i want selected value to be printed.pls save me sir.

Comment: Since the value is a variable, you need to use `ng-value="area.code"`

Comment: that i got code and name both things but my need is to get selected code inside "controller" not in "html"..:( are you got me sir..pls

Comment: If it's in the html it is in the controller as well. Check the [jsbin again](http://jsbin.com/yesoko/edit?html,js,output) for the submit button.